# Use GData to Parse XML with Text containing HTML

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, cocoa, gdata

I'm parsing an XML document using GData and some of the elements contain text with HTML tags.

```
<Paragraph>
Page 1 has some text
<br/>
<br/>
normal text
<br/>
<b>Strong Text</b>
<br />
<i>Italic Text</i>
<br />
normal text
</Paragraph>

NSString * para = [[[content elementsForName:@"Paragraph"] objectAtIndex:0]stringValue];
```

I'd like to the contents of the paragraph tag including the HTML tags to be assigned to the NSString para, but what I get is the text with all tags removed like below

```
Page 1 has some textnormal textStrong TextItalic Textnormal text
```

Is there any way to assign the entire string with HTML tags to an NSString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call XMLString method of GDataXMLNode. It will return you XML/HTML representation in string format.

```
NSString * para = [[[content elementsForName:@"Paragraph"] objectAtIndex:0] XMLString];
```